# git svn clone: branches moved from repo/ to repo/branches/ and "Malformed XML: no element found"

Tags: svn, git-svn

With git 2.8.2 and svn 1.9.4 under Cygwin, when cloning our repository with `git svn clone`, I hit a brick-wall at a certain commit:

```
r3640 = eb94... (refs/remotes/svn/trunk)
Found possible branch point: https://.../repo/<branchname> => https://.../repo/branches/<branchname>, 3641
Initializing parent: refs/remotes/svn/<branchname>@3641
Error from SVN, (175009): Malformed network data: The XML response contains invalid XML: Malformed XML: no element found
```

Observation #1: When cloning with `-r3600:HEAD`, that is, from a recent-enough commit, the operation succeeds. Tedious experimentation indicated that the problem appears when starting to clone from around 100 revisions before the problematic commit.

Observation #2: This appears to happen only for branches of the above form: mistakenly created in the repo root `repo/<branchname>`, and then moved to `repo/branches/<branchname>`

What is the problem and how to fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solution: enlarge your `--log-window-size` value (default: 100).

Caveat: larger window sizes inhibited the fetching of commits with many newly added files:

- window size of 7000 failed repeatedly after 3961 new files in a commit
- window size of 4000 failed after 4927 new files in a commit

There were actually 8430 new files in the affected commit.

This is all under Cygwin and I couldn't reproduce these problems on Linux, so your mileage may vary.

---

I noticed a similarity between the observed revision distance that causes the error and the default value of the `git svn fetch --log-window-size` option: both are 100.

Using a log window of 4000 solved the problem in my case, [others](http://blog.leneghan.com/2012/03/experiences-of-using-git-svn-on-large.html) have used even larger values for speeding up the initial clone/fetch operation.

I have verified the issue by cloning from 10 revisions before the problematic revision and using `--log-window-size=1` -- it failed again.

It would be interesting to know whether this is intended behavior or a bug on git-svn's side, as `--log-window-size` is documented to speed up the clone/fetching operation, and not as a necessity for fixing some branching issues.