# Git svn clone: Is it possible to resume after error Malformed XML: no element found?

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I'm attempting to do a one-way from subversion to Git migration of a large subversion repository using `git svn` with the following command (IMPORTANT after the migration only Git will be used):

```
git svn clone --no-minimize-url --trunk=/trunk/GBI --branches=/branches/GBI --tags=/tags/GBI --authors-file=authors.txt https://yyy/svn-repos/zzz/ GBI
```

After couple of hours running, the clone process crashes with the following error:

```
r79791 = 00349b8063f90447ea8a040751cd2a40e74b74f3 (refs/remotes/origin/trunk)
Error from SVN, (175009): Malformed network data: The XML response contains invalid XML: Malformed XML: no element found
```

Then I thought that maybe there is a clever way to resume the process right after the offending revision ... is that possible?

Any ideas what causes this error in the first place?

[The answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37278628/git-svn-clone-branches-moved-from-repo-to-repo-branches-and-malformed-xml-n) suggests using the `--log-window-size` to prevent this issue from happening in the first place ... can I add the option and retry from the failed revision? is this issue then a `git svn` memory usage issue or a problem that is connected solely to a corrupted subversion revision?

Is there a [git svn option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn) to robustify the process to ignore errors and not just stop the lengthy process due to this error?

UPDATE: I arrived at this point following the [Atlassian Stash Migrating to Git guide](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/svn-to-git-prepping-your-team-migration) which indicates using `git svn` and their `svn-migration-scripts.jar` implementation

Comment: Yre you doing a one-time conversion from SVN to Git and then use only Git afterwards, or do you use Git as frontend for the still existing SVN repository?

Comment: Good point! this is a one way only conversion, later will use only Git ... will update the Question

Comment: Nothing should go wrong if you try to rerun the import process. Say, `git svn fetch`.

Comment: Try subgit, I've follow https://stackoverflow.com/a/31841469/945014

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`git-svn` is **not** the right tool for one-time conversions of repositories or repository parts. It is a great tool if you want to use Git as frontend for an existing SVN server, but for one-time conversions you should **not** use `git-svn`, but `svn2git` which is much more suited for this use-case.

There are pleny tools called `svn2git`, the probably best one is the KDE one from https://github.com/svn-all-fast-export/svn2git. I strongly recommend using that `svn2git` tool. It is the best I know available out there and it is very flexible in what you can do with its rules files.

If you are not 100% about the history of your repository, `svneverever` from http://blog.hartwork.org/?p=763 is a great tool to investigate the history of an SVN repository when migrating it to Git.

---

Even though git-svn is easier to start with, here are some further reasons why using the KDE `svn2git` instead of `git-svn` is superior, besides its flexibility:

- the history is rebuilt much better and cleaner by `svn2git` (if the correct one is used), this is especially the case for more complex histories with branches and merges and so on
- the tags are real tags and not branches in Git
- with `git-svn` the tags contain an extra empty commit which also makes them not part of the branches, so a normal `fetch` will not get them until you give `--tags` to the command as by default only tags pointing to fetched branches are fetched also. With the proper svn2git tags are where they belong
- if you changed layout in SVN you can easily configure this with `svn2git`, with `git-svn` you will loose history eventually
- with `svn2git` you can also split one SVN repository into multiple Git repositories easily
- or combine multiple SVN repositories in the same SVN root into one Git repository easily
- the conversion is a gazillion times faster with the correct `svn2git` than with `git-svn`

There are many reasons why `git-svn` is worse and the KDE `svn2git` is superior. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I recently had

```
Error from SVN, (175009): Malformed network data: The XML response contains invalid XML: Malformed XML: unclosed token
```

which is almost the same and executing `git svn fetch` in the repository folder created by git clone as mentioned by [Mykola Gurov](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39661880/git-svn-clone-is-it-possible-to-resume-after-error-malformed-xml-no-element-fo#comment66695084_39661880) in a comment did continue at the revision where the error occurred and ran until the last SVN revision.